# How do I set a background Image to JPanel without overriding its contained components?

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel

I'm currently having trouble setting a background image for a JPanel.
The problem is that once I change the windows size to fullscreen, all Buttons disappear until I hover my mouse over them.

I hope someone is able to help.

Here's the sourcecode:

```
public class MFrame extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static Dimension Screen = null;
static MFrame MainFrame = null;

public static File FileForBild1 = new File("C:/xampp/bild.jpg");
public static File FileForBackground = new File("C:/xampp/Photos/background.jpg");


public static JButton FirstButton, SecondButton, ThirdButton, FourthButton, FifthButton, SixthButton;
public static JPanel MainPanel;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    MainFrame = new MFrame(Screen);
}

public MFrame(Dimension SSize){
    this.setLayout(null);
    double hoehe = SSize.getHeight();
    double breite = SSize.getWidth();
    int ButtonWidth = (int)(breite*.3);
    int ButtonHeight = (int)(hoehe*.35);
    MainPanel = new JPanel(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)SSize.getWidth(), (int)SSize.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                try{
                    img = ImageIO.read(FileForBackground); 
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)SSize.getWidth(), (int)SSize.getHeight(), 0, 0, 3888, 2592, null);
            }
        };

    FirstButton = new JButton(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)(breite*.3), (int)(hoehe*.35), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            try{
                img = ImageIO.read(FileForBild1); 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)(breite*.3), (int)(hoehe*.35), 0, 0, 960, 637, null);
        }
    };

SecondButton = new JButton("Bild2");
ThirdButton = new JButton("Bild3");
FourthButton = new JButton("Bild4");
FifthButton = new JButton("Bild5");
SixthButton = new JButton("Bild6");

FirstButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.025), (int)(hoehe*.1), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
SecondButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.35), (int)(hoehe*.1), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
ThirdButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.675), (int)(hoehe*.1), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);

FourthButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.025), (int)(hoehe*.5), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
FifthButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.35), (int)(hoehe*.5), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
SixthButton.setBounds((int)(breite*.675), (int)(hoehe*.5), ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);


MainPanel.setSize((int)breite, (int)hoehe);
MainPanel.setLayout(null);
MainPanel.add(FirstButton);
MainPanel.add(SecondButton);
MainPanel.add(ThirdButton);
MainPanel.add(FourthButton);
MainPanel.add(FifthButton);
MainPanel.add(SixthButton);


setSize((int)breite, (int)hoehe);
setTitle("Test");
add(MainPanel);
setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues, but the main ones are:

- You're not calling the super's painting method within your override. This will break your component's painting chain and can cause child components not to draw.
- You're reading in a file within a painting method -- this unnecessarily slows down a method that should be lightning fast and is totally unnecessary. Read the file in once in the constructor and store it to a variable.
- You should override paintComponent, not paint
- And again should call the super's paintComponent method as the first call in your override.

So do something like this:

```
MainPanel = new JPanel(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // the img field should be declared as an instance field and created in the constructor
    // BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)SSize.getWidth(), (int)SSize.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        // first call the super's method
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // file reading should be done once, say in a constructor, not here
        // img = ImageIO.read(FileForBackground); 

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (int)SSize.getWidth(), (int)SSize.getHeight(), 0, 0, 3888, 2592, null);
    }
};
```

Make sure any JPanels added to this image displaying component are set as non-opaque so that the image can show through.